# A helper named could not be found when trying to render component in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have the following router setup:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route("login");
  this.route("dashboard");
  this.route("projects", function() {
    this.route("show", {path: "/:project_id"});

    this.route('tasks', {path: "/:project_id/tasks" },function() {
      this.route('new', {path: "/new"});
      this.route('show', {path: "/:task_id"});
    });
  });
});
```

And, in `templates/projects/show.hbs`, I'd like to render the component for creating a new task ( the component is automatically generated by ember, but I have my own template and controllers at `controllers/projects/tasks/new.js` and `templates/projects/tasks/new.hbs`  ). I tried the following:

```
  {{tasks/new model=model}}
```

But I receive this error:

```
Assertion Failed: A helper named "tasks/new" could not be found
```

What is the proper way of fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{tasks/new` here `task/new` can be a Component or Helper but can't be template hbs.
If you want to include `tasks/new` inside `templates/projects/show.hbs` then I would encourage you to create component for `tasks/new` and include it where ever you require.

You can give it try by mentioning different templateName for template hbs. using `templateName` property. 
Inside `show.js` route file define `templateName: 'projects/tasks/new'`